# Hide/show children component in component inside ngFor

Tags: angular

I would like to display the component 'app-action-buttons-modele' in my child component only if "showButtons" is true. However, "showButtons" is not always true in my ngFor* loop.

I tried something like this but I can't get it right:

In my parent component 'app-theme' :

```
<app-action-buttons-modele
  (addQuestion)="addQuestion($event)"
  (addTheme)="addTheme($event)"
>
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <ng-container formArrayName="children">
    <ul>
      <app-sous-theme
        [formControlName]="i"
        *ngFor="let question of childrenFormArray?.controls; index as i"
        [titre]="question.value.titre"
        class="app-sous-theme"
        (remove)="deleteChildrenFromArray(i)"
        (up)="changePlace(-1, i)"
        (down)="changePlace(1, i)"
        (edit)="editQuestion(i)"
        [showButtons]="isButtonsShow[i]"
      >
      </app-sous-theme>
    </ul>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

'app-theme' TS

```
isButtonsShow = [];
addQuestion(question) {
 this.isButtonsShow.push(false)
}
```

In my children component 'app-sous-theme':

```
<app-action-buttons-modele
  *ngIf="showButtons[i]"
  (remove)="remove.emit()"
  (addTheme)="addSousTheme($event)"
  (addQuestion)="addQuestion($event)"
> 
</app-action-buttons-modele>
```

'app-sous-theme' TS

```
  @Input() showButtons: any;
```

Comment: Array mutation and change detection don't go very well together. In the `addQuestion` method, try to reassign the array like this: `this.isButtonsShow = [...this.isButtonsShow, false];` instead of pushing the new value. See if that helps

Comment: It doesn't help. Actually 'i' in `*ngIf="showButtons[i]"` is unknown in my children component 'app-sous-theme'. I understand why, but i don't know how to do that in an other way.

Comment: In `app-sous-theme` you should only use `showButtons`, because that one already has the value that you pass in from the parent component. There is no need to index that. `showButtons` in the child component is not an array, but a boolean value that you can already use.

Comment: Ok it works, I was not far from the goal! 
Thanks for your help. I just remove the `i` on `showButtons`.